# How to use trained pytorch model for prediction

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have a pretrained pytorch model which is saved in .pth format. How can i use it for prediction on new dataset in a separate python file.

I need a detailed guide.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and the specific issue encountered; SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I used a jupyter notebook which was made by someone else. I used it to train my model and on that it was predicting well on test dataset but i could not understand how to use model on another file which is the main goal of my project. @Edwin Cheong's answer helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a pretrained model you should load the state on a new instance of the architecture as explained in the [docs/tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html):

Here `models` is imported beforehand:

```py
model = models.vgg16()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_weights.pth')) # This line uses .load() to read a .pth file and load the network weights on to the architecture.
model.eval() # enabling the eval mode to test with new samples.
```

If you are using a custom architecture you only need to change the first line.

```py
model = MyCustomModel()
```

After enabling the `eval` mode, you can proceed as follows:

- Load your data into a `Dataset` instance and then in a `DataLoader`.
- Make your predictions with the data.
- Calculate metrics on the results.

More about `Dataset` and `DataLoader` [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Well for prediction theres something called forward pass

```py
import torch
from torch_model import Model # Made up package

# select gpu when available, else work with cpu resources
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = Model()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('weights.pt'))

model = model.to(device) # Set model to gpu
model.eval();

inputs = torch.random.randn(1, 3, 224, 224) # Dtype is fp32
inputs = inputs.to(device) # You can move your input to gpu, torch defaults to cpu

# Run forward pass
with torch.no_grad():
  pred = model(inputs)

# Do something with pred
pred = pred.detach().cpu().numpy() # remove from computational graph to cpu and as numpy
```